# How did "currently a student" got on my Careers profile? And how to remove it?

Tags: support, jobs

See my profile https://careers.stackoverflow.com/tomasfejfar - there is a "Currently a student. " as a first sentence. I linked my linkedin account, but that resulted in appending other positions rather than replacing "student".

There is no edit button there (even if I am in edit mode). I can edit tags, if I'm looking for a job, but not this text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you edit your Careers profile, you have "I am currently a student" checkbox to the right of "Education" caption:

> [image]

For some reason you have it checked at the moment, either you misclicked it when editing at some point or maybe it was imported from the LinkedIn account and wasn't auto updated.

Anyway just untick the box and it would be saved instantly.

Comment: It did the trick. Thank you.